# Why netTcp must have an other protocol?

Tags: wcf, service, binding

Why the netTcp has an other protocol ? Why BasicHttp and WS are in the same protocol ? Can someone explain me ? Thank you

[WCF SERVICE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxpwn.png)

Answer (score 0):

**BasicHttpBinding:** 
                 Basic web service communication. Exposes WCF services as legacy ASMX web services. Used for interoperability. No security by default.

**WSHttpBinding:** Web services with WS-* support. Supports transactions and reliable messaging.

**NetTcpBinding:** Communication between WCF applications across computers. Supports duplex contracts and transactions.

For More clarifications check the following links

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/431291/WCF-Services-Choosing-the-appropriate-WCF-binding

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/wcf/VE8a200713-Understanding-various-types-of-WCF-bindings.html

http://wcftutorial.net/wcf-types-of-binding.aspx

Comment: Did u checked that links

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you understand under "protocol".

Will try to explain: in any case any WCF service works with TCP/IP transport protocol. 
When you start the service, it listens IP socket, then accepts incoming bytes[] and then the difference is in application level protocol.

To transform bytes into .NET objects there is a pipeline which starts from so called MessageEncoder. In the encoder bytes are deserialized into a Message object. By default there is three type of encoders:

- text encoder, which transforms byte[] into string
- MTOM encoder.

> MTOM is a mechanism for transmitting large binary attachments with SOAP messages as raw bytes, allowing for smaller messages

- binary encoder, which transforms byte[] into .NET object using .net specific binary serializer which is not compatible with non .net systems

So here is the difference:

- BasicHttp binding uses text encoder. It interprets incoming bytes as HTTP request and transforms byte stream into Http headers and body. Then the body is deserialized depending on the specific type of the binding and message deserializer, which is a part of service behavior.
  In one case this body is deserialized as SOAP/XML (BasicHttp), in other as XML or JSON (webHttpBinding).
- WS bindins can use text encoder as well as MTOM encoder. In second case encoder knows how to take from the byte[] stream textual XML/SOAP part and binary attachment.
- netTcp binding uses binary encoder and deserializes bytes direct into object.

So protocol part in the binding address simply distinguishes this two major cases "http://" for bindings which a kind of standartised and compatible with non-.NET world, text based. And "net.tcp" for pure windows+.NET stuff.